# Forbid AngularJS to reload IFrame

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I integrated an iframe to my angularjs app and I also can communicate with my Iframe. I used the following way:

```
<iframe ng-if="reloadIFrame" class="embed-responsive-item" src="/context/iframe_integration.html" 
        onload="angular.element(document.documentElement).injector().get('$rootScope').$broadcast('iFrameLoadedEvent', event);">
</iframe>
```

I catch the broadcasted event in a service and save the reference to it:

```
// ...
var iFrameInterface = false;

$rootScope.$on('iFrameLoadedEvent', function(ev, event) {
        if(!iFrameInterface){
            iFrameInterface = angular.element(event.target)[0].contentWindow.iFrameInterface;
// ...
```

The problem is the following: If I navigate to another position in my app and go back to the site where my iframe is integrated the iframe is reloaded and my reference to it is old. I can update the reference to my iframe interface but the question is **"Is it possible to integrate the iframe once and never reload again?"**

I don't want to reload the content of the iframe everytime if I navigate to another page and reload it if I come to the page again.

Thank you...

Comment: Did you try to put it outside your `ng-view`?

Comment: or caching should do the trick, you could do eager loading and cache the get request in angular, this would prevent angular from making a request and just pull from cache, but this depends on where your iframe is pointing. (see request cache and template cache)